# DISCORD BOT slash command not working showing "the application did not respond "

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, javascript-objects

so whenever I write "/anycommand" it always replies with "the application did not respond". this is the code i copied from a youtuber (this is my first time at everything don't hate me)

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Embed } = require(`discord.js`);

module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName("embed")
.setDescription("Returns an embed."),
async execute(interaction, client){
  
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder () 
.setTitle(`Hey! it's dum bot.`)
.setDescription('I am dumb.')
.setColor(0x92a8d1)
.setImage(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
.setTimestamp()
.setAuthor({
    name: interaction.user.tag
})
const channel = await client.channels.cache.get('1099293847529459763');
await interaction.deleteReply();
await interaction.reply({
    embeds: [embed]
});
},
} ;
```

the code has no errors the command is registered under the "integration" tab when you right click on the bot, it has all the perms and the bot is online. the developer portal seems good but i chatGPT the problem and it said the commands should be under the "application commands" but there is no such thing there , i even tried changing the token and reinviting the bot and also everything is updated.